# C++: How to iterate through a double pointer pointing to an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

In the following piece of code, I am iterating through a pointer to an array of pointers to TreeNode objects. Below is my code where I iterate through the array:

```
TreeNode* childListPointer = *currNode->children;


for (TreeNode* currChild = childListPointer; currChild != NULL; currChild = ++childListPointer) {
    std::cout << "Iteration" << endl;
}
```

And below is the code of my TreeNode struct:

```
typedef struct TreeNode { 
   int key;
   int val;
   bool flag;
   int num_children;
   TreeNode **children;
} TreeNode;
```

However, my code keeps getting stuck an infinite loop, even when the length of the array is a small number (e.x. 4 or 5).

Note: The autograder system **does not allow me to modify the TreeNode struct**.

Comment: `currChild != NULL` this will always be `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is a size and count.

```
int num_children;
TreeNode **children;
```

Based off that, you can make a simple range adapter for `for(:)` loops:

```
template<class It>
struct range {
  It s, f;
  It begin() const { return s; }
  It end() const { return f; }
  range(It b, It e):s(b),f(e) {}
  range(It b, std::ptrdiff_t count):range(b, b+count) {}
};
```

now, just:

```
for(TreeNode* child : range{ currNode->children, currNode->num_children })
{
  std::cout << "Iteration" << endl;
}
```

Prior to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you need a `make_range`:

```
template<class It>
range<It> make_range( It b, It e ) { return {b,e}; }
template<class It>
range<It> make_range( It b, std::ptrdiff_t c ) { return {b,c}; }

for(TreeNode* child : make_range( currNode->children, currNode->num_children ))
{
  std::cout << "Iteration" << endl;
}
```

because "deduction guides" where added in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

And you are done.  You can now iterate over the children without doing any pointer arithmetic and getting confused.

...

If you are stuck in [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currNode->num_children; ++i)
{
  TreeNode* child = currNode->children[i];
  std::cout << "Iteration" << endl;
}
```

or

```
TreeNode** it = currNode->children;
TreeNode** end = it+currNode->num_children;
for (; it != end; ++it)
{
  TreeNode* child = *it;
  std::cout << "Iteration" << endl;
}
```

which is almost exactly what the `range` version compiles down to.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :D. Is there any way to iterate through the double pointer array without modifying the TreeNode struct?

Comment: @AdamLee That type and function(s) are not part of `TreeNode`.  They are just utility functions you write and use.  `TreeNode` is completely unchanged.